# POST a HTML Form programmatically?

Tags: vb.net, post, asp.net-3.5, forms

I need to POST a HTML form to a 3rd party website (a Mass-SMS texting system).

In the past I've done this by forwarding to a page containing a form I've pre-populated and hidden (using `display:none`), then I've ran a javascript function at the end of the page to automatically submit this form.

However I'm hoping theres someway I can do all this programmatically (as I don't care about the response, and the user doesn't need to see the page the form is being posted to).

How can I do this? Cheers

Comment: How did you do this have you got some code ?

Comment: @user985197 It's quite common practice, here's an example - http://spamtech.co.uk/tips/automatically-submit-a-form-using-javascript/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a [WebClient.UploadValues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9w7b4fz7.aspx) method to send an HTTP POST request to a remote server from your code behind. Just fill up the name/value collection with the values coming from the hidden fields.

Comment: Easy way to do it server side. Saw this method ages ago but forgot about it.. Now I might use it more often now. Keep it `DRY`! Thanks +1

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to get into PHP, you can very easily use cURL for this.
Otherwise it's going to be quite difficult using just Javascript.

[See here for a detailed tutorial](http://www.askapache.com/htaccess/sending-post-form-data-with-php-curl.html).

Comment: This would not be an option as this is a feature I'm looking to use on a large .NET application, but thanks anyway for the suggestion.

Comment: JavaScript on its own will be difficult. But using jQueries AJAX `$.post` method is a breeze for client side posting and handling. from server to another, multiple request and response handling.