# add dynamic data to api url in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, sms

I have a SMS API which I want to integrate to my application built in asp.net n-tier. The api should take contact number dynamically through database. API only contain a URL path having information about username, password, recipient no., sender id and message.

My api code is like this

```
http://www.domain.com/API/WebSMS/Http/v1.000a/index.php?username=myusername&password=XXX&sender=mysenderid&to=9876543210&message=Thank+you+name+for+contacting&reqid=123&format={json|text}&route_id=5555.
```

I am new to .net as I know how to do it in php but have no idea to integrate in .net. Any help will be appreciated.
I do have a registration page from where data is entered into database table.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you wan to make an HTTP post to the URL with the values in the query string, check out this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5090086/how-to-simulate-http-post-programatically-in-asp-net) answer, in this case

Comment: actually I wanted that after filling form when user clicks on submit button the above sms api url should be fired which takes values passed in the form and sms is sent