# How to POST HTML form programmatically and get response

Tags: c#, javascript, html

I have a form that gets username and password and after submitting it shows some information of that account. the form is:

```
<form id="LoginForm" target="Window81525062.79020184" action="Login.aspx" method="post" name="LoginForm">

      <input id="userID" type="text" maxlength="20" style="WIDTH: 160px; HEIGHT: 24px" onkeypress="CheckEnter()">

      <input id="Password" type="password" maxlength="20" style="WIDTH: 160px; HEIGHT: 24px" onkeypress="CheckEnter()">

      <div id="b2" class="social-media-shareTAK" style="width: 60px;">
          <div class="inner"></div>
          <ul>
              <li>
                  <a title="enter" target="_blank">
                       <img src="/DL/Classes/BUTTON/images/Login.png" alt="" style="width: 38px; height: 38px; margin-top: 4px; cursor: pointer; position: absolute; left: 7px;">
                  </a>
              </li>
          </ul>
       </div>
</form>
```

now I want to enter about 100 account username and password from a database and store information of these accounts to another database. How should I do this?
( I prefer C# but if there is better way please let me know) thanks :)

Comment: can you please clear your requirement.. posting the form in background using jquery /ajax is popular way.. and in last line you told  you want to insert the 100 accounts details from one database to another.. so its different task.. what is the exact requirement?

Comment: This question is confusing, it sounds like you want to migrate account details from one database to another, not sure why you are posting the from code, perhaps you can clarify and we can try to assist you.

Comment: yes, It was an old database that we don't have direct access to it, now we want to improve it and we need its data.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a C# sample  (server side code gives better control so I recommend that)

```
        StringBuilder postData = new StringBuilder();

        postData.Append("USERNAME_FIELD_NAME =" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode("USERNAME") + "&");
        postData.Append("PASSWORD_FIELD_NAME =" + HttpUtility.UrlEncode("PASSWORD"));

        // Now to Send Data.
        StreamWriter writer = null;

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(THE_URL);
        request.Method = "POST";
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.ContentLength = postData.ToString().Length;
        try
        {
            writer = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream());
            writer.Write(postData.ToString());

        HttpWebResponse WebResp = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();                     

        //Now, we read the response (the string), and output it.
        Stream Answer = WebResp.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader _Answer = new StreamReader(Answer);
        Console.WriteLine(_Answer.ReadToEnd());

        }
        finally
        {
            if (writer != null)
                writer.Close();
        }
```

Sources/HowTo's:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/debx8sh9.aspx

http://forums.asp.net/t/1048041.aspx?How+to+programmatically+POST+data+to+an+aspx+page+

[How to simulate HTTP POST programatically in ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5090086/how-to-simulate-http-post-programatically-in-asp-net)

Comment: The value of username and password fields also need to be encoded, e.g. with `HttpUtility.UrlEncode`.

Comment: thankx, but it says:
You must write ContentLength bytes to the request stream before calling [Begin]GetResponse.

Comment: @farshad22 .. answer updated with several sources to other samples/ways .. make your pick :)

Comment: I can help with how to do and provide samples by answering your question, but I can't do the work or teach how to understand. If you need help with that, you need to hire someone.