# How to Call Web API in Asp.Net WebForm?

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, asp.net-web-api

[image: screenshot of text]

I want to call this API in C#, same parameter will be passed.

It's working fine on POSTMAN; I just want to call from asp.net Web Form

Comment: What is stopping you? Are you looking for [HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netcore-3.1) ?

Comment: i don't know how to pass multiple parameters i

Comment: i wanna cal as it is from code behind/back end

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to simulate HTTP POST programmatically in ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5090086/how-to-simulate-http-post-programmatically-in-asp-net)

Comment: Please don't paste code as screenshots; copy-and-paste the text instead. It will also benefit those using screen readers or other assistive text functionality in a way that images won't.

Answer (score 1):

Use that :

```
var values = new Dictionary<string, string>
{
    { "thing1", "hello" },
    { "thing2", "world" }
};

var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);

var response = await client.PostAsync("http://www.example.com/recepticle.aspx", content);

var responseString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```